# Where to Download Full Apache Camel Core JAR for OSGi Application with Ant Build System?

Tags: maven, apache-kafka, apache-camel, osgi

I am working on a Java OSGi application and need to include the Apache Camel Core library for Kafka message consumption. My project is built using Ant, and I am trying to manually download the necessary JAR file.

I attempted to download the camel-core JAR from the Maven repository for version 4.2.0 at MVN Repository (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-core/4.2.0), but the downloaded JAR is only 3KB and seems to lack essential classes (e.g., org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder).

This issue persists across different versions I checked on the Maven repository. Can anyone guide me on where to find the complete camel-core JAR suitable for an OSGi environment? Specifically, I'm looking for a version that includes classes required for Kafka consumer integration.

Comment: Don't use Ant, but Maven or Gradle.

Comment: The application is built using ant, changing it would involve a lot of work. I have to stick to ant unfortunately

Comment: Not changing it just means to move the work to next year. Ant is deprecated and not really used any more.

Comment: There is currently no OSGi support in Camel 4.x. For Camel 3.x, you can get an idea of the required libraries for each component by looking at the Karaf features.xml. https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/camel/karaf/apache-camel/3.21.2/apache-camel-3.21.2-features.xml

Comment: The mvnrepository site you link references _a lot_ of compile dependencies - 29 of them. Moving to another build system is a lot of work. Keeping ant happy means that you'll have to download dependencies manually, that otherwise would have come in automatically. It's also a lot of work (e.g.: I'm not sure if those 29 dependencies come with their own optional or mandatory transitive dependencies)